# Plot every nth element in an array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm coding a simple neural network from scratch. The neural network is implemented in a method `simple_1_layer_classification_NN`. For every Epoch (training run of the neural net) as you can see from the `for loop` (in the code below), I append the cost (error margin) value to an array `costs`. The thing is when the training runs can be as many as thousands or even millions. Meaning the `costs` array can have so many `cost` elements appended it.

As I don't want to plot thousands or millions of data-points on a graph, what I want to do is, no matter how many elements are in the `costs` array, I only want to plot 100 data points from it, spread-out as equally as possible. E.g. if there are 10 elements, then plot all 10 elements. If there are 100 elements, plot all 100 elements. Anything above a 100, plot only 100 data points equally spaced out. E.g. with 200 plot every other data point. With 500, plot every 5th element. Even if it's 102 elements, then plot only 100 data-points, as spaced out as possible. I hope this makes sense. Is this possible to do? Note, I'm only include part of the code that's most relevant to the question. Where there are comments with dots `# ......` I'm just indicating that there's code here, but I didn't include it, as it's not relevant to the question.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```py
 def simple_1_layer_classification_NN(self, dataset_input_matrix, output_data_labels, input_dimension, epochs, activation_func='sigmoid', learning_rate=0.2, cost_func='squared_error'):
        # ...............
        cost = float()
        costs = []
        # ................

        # We perform the training based on the number of epochs specified
        for i in range(epochs):

                 #....................
                 # Cost: the cost function to calculate the prediction error margin
                 cost = chosen_cost_func(pred, output_data_labels[ri])

                costs.append(cost)
        #.....................

    plt.plot(costs)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
x = xdata[::10]
x = ydata[::10]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

it will plot each 10th points out of xdata, ydata

In your case

```
x = None
y = None
l = len(xdata) 
if l < 100:
    x = xdata[::]
    y = ydata[::]
elif l < 200:
    x = xdata[::2]
    y = ydata[::2]
elif l < 500:
    x = xdata[::5]
    y = ydata[::5]
```

UPDATE

Not sure if it is relevant, but you could also try to use custom strides. It will point to the same data buffer, but use different metadata to step over data in strides.

Function to look at is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided, and it is in the stride_tricks for a reason - you'll get some time to get used to it. Set writeable to False so you won't mess original data. Simple example is [here](https://ipython-books.github.io/46-using-stride-tricks-with-numpy/).

Comment: my apologies for the late reply. Thank you for the suggested solution. Your first suggestion helped me to formulate the right structure for what I'm after. Basically any array with items above 100, I simply divided the length of array by 100, then use that number in the slicing style you mentioned, i.e. [::number]. I made sure to cast the number to an integer of course (as it's an index). It's done the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Wrt to your second suggestion, I read about `strides`. I'm not sure that it fits with what I'm looking for, as I understand it's more to describe, in any dimension, how many bytes we need to jump over in the data buffer to go from one item to the next, and it also helps in also helps make your code run faster, according to one of the tutorials I read, where rather than copying data from one array to a new array by looping through the former, you simply use `strides` with the original array, with the desired shape and strides and it's much more efficient. That's my understanding of it anyway.

Comment: @Hazzaldo yes, strides are more of an efficiency mechanism, but I image you could construct stride to jump over n*bytes_per_element, so it serve your purpose. Never done it before myself, so no code. Just to remember, [::10] will copy data from original buffer, so you'll get more memory usage, while strides in theory is just a metadata, no more memory and data copy.